# Grammaticality of "the tooltip reads"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Is it correct to use the word "read" in these sentences? If not, what would be more appropriate word to use instead?

> The status-bar now reads: Click to run the currently highlighted cell.
>
> The tool-tip reads: Click to run the currently highlighted cell.

Comment: This is the so-called [middle construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/5730/300). And yes, perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВBẞ8 This sort of thing is super-common in Romance, where it uses a reflexive pronoun to indicate the “middle voice” (not that they call it that).

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs, I'm not entirely convinced that *read* in the OP's sentence is a true *middle intransitive*. Typical middle constructions such as *It doesn't print* or *It washes well* are about how something is done or if it can be done at all. Similarly, *This book reads well* is concerned with the ease of reading the book. [In other languages, as *tchrist* points out, the reflexive is commonly used to convey such meanings. Eg. German: *Es liest sich gut*.]. But in the OP's sentence there is no concern as to whether or how the text may be read, but simply as to what it says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they are correct. "Read" can refer to the action performed by a human being when looking by text, or it can refer to the text itself or the medium containing the text.

> I read the words, "Hello, world."
>
> The message reads, "Hello, world."
>
> The text reads, "Hello, world."

All are correct.

Answer (score 4):

I feel that *read* is correct in these cases.  People might use *says* instead, but the status bar and tool-tip are incapable of speech outside of text-to-speech setups.

In all but edge cases, the user must read what is being reported by the status bar and various tool-tips.