# The board writes well. He walks the dog

Tags: semantics

During the orientation programme conducted for the resource persons in English in Hyderabad,one of the professors wrote a sentence on the board and it is given below

> The board writes well.

She asked us to say whether the verb *write* is transitive or intransitive. We could not satisfactorily answer the question.because It did not look like either transitive. or intransitive she explained something which I forgot so I need explanation from the scholars

Another example  is

> He walks the dog everyday

I found the sentence in a text for Tenth class students

The sentences are indifferent from the sentences like *he writes well* and *the dog walks*.

- I would like to know the function of the verb and the subject in the sentences above,  I know that the two verbs are different

I would like to know whether the topic comes under semantics.

EDIT
This is not a duplicate of the question ["The ticket is printing" vs "...is being printed"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5725/the-ticket-is-printing-vs-is-being-printed) because I am not asking whether the sentences mentioned above are grammatically correct, my question is focused on their syntax and semantics.

Comment: It’s borderline ungrammatical is what it is. Some verbs can be used unaccusatively (“the book reads well”), but _write_ is not such a verb in my English. Syntactically, it is of course intransitive here since it has no object argument.

Comment: This is the middle construction. See the linked question for details. As Janus says, whether *this particular* middle construction is grammatical or idiomatic, is debatable. Maybe it is in Indian English, I do not know.

Comment: i will edit or ask a new question

Comment: Please read the [**help center**](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) adding another example will not help to reopen your question. You need to explain why the answer(s) in the original question, of which yours is said to be a duplicate,  do *not* answer your question

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thank you very much for your suggestions

Comment: Keep in mind next time someone suggests your question is a duplicate, check the the actual question and any answer(s) posted. If you find the answer in the older post, that is a great result and you can actually cast the decisive vote to close your own question as a duplicate. RegDwight is  a moderator on this site and moderators can close questions with a single vote. I realize this sounds all a bit too much but bear with it, over time you'll learn the "culture" and welcome the guidelines.

Comment: Feel free to edit and expand on the reason why you think your question is different. I just wanted to show you how it's done, before too much time lapsed by.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A.thank you very much fot your help

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question. The duplicate contains a good answer about the  _middle construction_. The _middle construction_ is a superordinate of _ergatives_ and _mediopassives_. _The board writes well_ is an example of the mediopassive which is not mentioned in the other answer. Nevertheless, the addition of the dog example muddies the issue and should probably be retracted. (Did the professor write the dog sentence on the board too?)

Comment: 'She asked us to say whether the verb _write_ is transitive or intransitive.' Can you supply the actual quote (which is important)? Did she mean 'Is the verb _write_ in this usage transitive or intransitive?'? / In an example that is incontestably acceptable (which I'd say the one on the board isn't), 'Her novels always sell well', 'sell' displays the _middle usage/voice_.  There is no overt object, so this can't be labelled a transitive usage. But note that 'Is V a transitive verb?' is ill-formed; it's **usages** that are transitive or intransitive.

Comment: @Shoe The confusion in terminology (focusing on the episodic interpretation [the glass broke] vs the typical middle usage having  to do with permanent properties of entities [this glass breaks easily]; your statement is _one_ view) is mentioned in [This wine is _drinking nicely_ ... does anything else 'drink nicely'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95805/this-wine-is-drinking-nicely-does-anything-else-drink-nicely).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. Thanks for the link. I agree about the terminological confusion: ergative, mediopassive, middle construction, middle voice, middle verb, middle intransitive, unaccusative, activo-passive, passival, and Uncle Tom Cobley et al.

Comment: He may have meant "bard", instead of "board".

Comment: @Greg Lee Best joke on ELU for ages. Sorry about the poor company: But _she_ probably didn't commence: "Now watch the board while I go through it." An editorial panel, perhaps. _The board write well_.

Comment: @Edwin.she meant the whiteboard and she did write: "the board writes well"

Comment: Have you *read* the question I linked? It talks about syntax and semantics. Also, the second example you added has nothing to do with the first. It has a completely different syntax and semantics.

Comment: @RegDWight. you are right. I need explanation

Comment: my question should  not have been down voted after so many comments

Comment: Consider “This tent sleeps six. This bed sleeps two. This bed sleeps well.”. Perhaps the answer should address the issues here.