# Inanimate things doing things

Tags: grammaticality

My question is about inanimate things doing things - like the new smartphone will ship out tomorrow; the ship will launch tomorrow; the book will publish next month. We see that often these days. Is                    that now standard English?

Comment: It's always been normal English, for some active verbs, to have inanimate subjects, like _The ship left yesterday_ or _The phone is ringing_. What's changed is that some other verbs are being used this way as well. Everything in a sentence depends on the main verb; they all have individual rules, prohibitions, and affordances, and these change pretty often.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["This wine is drinking nicely" : does anything else 'drink nicely' etc?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95805/this-wine-is-drinking-nicely-does-anything-else-drink-nicely)

Comment: There is a brand of liquorice I see in the UK which is described on the packet as 'soft eating'.

Comment: John Lawler: The two examples you give is/are "normal English'. Multiply that a 1000-fold: The school closed for holidays; the holidays got spoilt owing to the C19; the C19 is a mysterious disease in how it affects different countries. But to say "the vaccine will launch/inaugurate tomorrow" to me is a new trend - and widely accepted. We used to see "the vaccine will be launched/inaugurated tomorrow".

Comment: Edwin Ashworth: "The wine is drinking nicely' - and now it's gone? Rilly?!

Comment: Michael Harvey: "Soft eating" there is like an adjective, not a verb.